# Special Values of a Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

Right now I am creating a class which represents a closed interval. Its core functionality is to provide an `intersect` method.

```py
class Interval:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        # check a <= b otherwise swap
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def intersect(self, other):
        a = self.a if self.a > other.a else other.a
        b = self.b if self.b < other.b else other.b
        if b < a:
            # return some value representing an empty interval, providing the intersect method
        return Intervall(a,b)
```

It should be possible to represent special Values like all points [-oo,oo] or the empty set {}. Which still serve the `intersect` method. My current approach is to create a new class, but this seems kinda tedious.

```py
class EmptyInterval:
    def intersect(self, other):
        return self
```

Assuming those special values' intersect methods take precedence I'd prepend on the Intervall class' method:

```py
class Intervall:
    ...
    def intersect(self,other):
        if not isinstance(self, other):
            other.intersect(self)
        ...
```

To clarify - the following should be legal:

```py
a = Intervall(1,2)
b = Intervall(3,4)

c = a.intersect(b)  # resulting in an empty interval

c.intersect(a)      # resulting again in an empty interval
```

Is there some elegant / more pythonic / less nauseating ugly way to implement such a behavior?

First I thought of inheritance, but that seems quite unfitting because of the precedence those special values should have; i.e. I do not know how to implement it via inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a couple special functions in your class `Interval`:

```
@staticmethod
def everything():
    return Interval(-math.inf, math.inf)

@staticmethod
def nothing():
    return Interval(math.nan, math.nan)
```

You may find it more natural to write `nothing()` like this:

```
    return Interval(0, 0)
```

or this:

```
    return Interval(math.inf, math.inf)
```

It rather depends on your other code, and what you think is the most natural way to represent the empty interval.  Note that any less or greater comparison with NAN will return false, so this may have some impact on which way you decide to represent the empty interval (for example is `nothing().intersect(nothing())` supposed to be true or false?).

Comment: thanks for the answer! Neither nothing().intersect(nothing()) is supposed to return nothing(), which would be the case with Interval(math.nan, math.nan). I just came up with a possible solution myself, going to post it in a minute. Maybe you could comment on that. Afterwards I'll close the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be another solution:

Instead of passing a,b separately, I could pass a tuple (a,b). Further I could declare a couple of singletons as class variables. During instantiation I'd pass that singleton and would only have to check whether that value is one of the singletons and act accordingly.

```py
class Interval:
    EMPTY = object()
    EVERYTHING = object()
    def __init__(self, bounds):
        self.bound = bounds

    def intersect(self, other):
        if self.bounds == self.EMPTY or other.bounds == self.EMPTY:
            return Interval(self.EMPTY)

        ...
 
        if b < a:
            return Interval(self.EMPTY)

        return Interval((a,b))
```

I guess this maybe less error prone than John's answer, because of the general behavior math.inf and / or math.nan impose. Also it would allow to strictly forbid those values to be passed, as Interval(math.nan, 1) would be nonsensical.

But it may be more effort to implement in a more complex setting.

Comment: By doing this you lose all type safety: `EMPTY` is not an instance of `Interval`.  Maybe that's OK for you, but for some people it would be a deal breaker.

Comment: Shure that's true. But as I said I am more in for specifying all the behaviour my class is going to have. Any how: thanks for your time!